# Can I change the sound location?

Tags: java, javax.sound.sampled

I would like to know if i can play a sound on the right/left speaker/headphone in java by using sound.sampled?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The AudioDevice Class defines and encapsulates the audio device's basic information and characteristics.

Click [here](http://download.java.net/media/java3d/javadoc/1.3.2/javax/media/j3d/AudioDevice.html)! to visit Audiodevice class page.